# Memory leaks found when Local Binder has a reference to Service

Tags: android

I've used non static inner class as binder to all my services.however when i run the MAT tool to check the Memory leaks i found that all my binder class not getting clear. so i found the following two link related to this issue.

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=6426

following link discues a workaround for this:using weak refreshments 
http://www.ozdroid.com/#!BLOG/2010/12/19/How_to_make_a_local_Service_and_bind_to_it_in_Android

1. Since this is a known issue with the current version of the android SDK, is there a idea of when it will be fixed?

2.The solution provided above  is a standered recommended approach? or is there any workaround to fix.

3 other than this what sort of memory leaks introduce when using the binder pattern.

Sam

I'm using the Android SDK 2.2.

Answer (score 3):

I found a similar leak issue when you pass a callback Object through a Binder to a Service: [Binder preventing garbage collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7976322/binder-preventing-garbage-collection)

I believe that when you bind to a service the ServiceConnection Object probably won't be collected until you unbind. Thus your ServiceConnection ideally shouldn't hold on to anything that consumes a lot of memory or something you may want garbage collected while the connection is ongoing. This means that a non-static inner class is probably not a good idea because non-static inner classes have a pointer to their parent, that means the parent will not be garbage collected until the connection is closed.

I don't think this is something that can really be fixed, it is necessary to keep the ServiceConnection Object alive as long as there is a connection, we user-engineers just need to be careful about what side-effects that may have.