# Android memory leak accountmanager dependency

Tags: android, memory-leaks, retrofit2, accountmanager

For my project I'm using Retrofit for my API calls. 
For authentication I'm using JWT tokens. 
For storage and refresh flow of that token I'm using [Google's AccountManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html).

The ApiService class is an singleton which I build as follows:

```
 private ApiService(AccountManager accountManager) {
        mAccountManager = accountManager;
        build();
    }

    public static synchronized ApiService getInstance(AccountManager accountManager) {
        if (mInstance == null) {
            mInstance = new ApiService(accountManager);
        }
        return mInstance;
    }
```

In this class I'm building the OkHttp3 client and the Retrofit service.

Okhttp3 has a nice method when the server responds with a challenge so I set this up like this:

```
 OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .authenticator(new ApiAuthenticator(mAccountManager))
```

As you can see I'm setting a custom implementation of the Okhttp3 Authenticator which looks like this:

```
    /**
     * 2017 App-vise.
     * Created by daangeurts on 31/07/2017.
     */
    public class ApiAuthenticator implements Authenticator {

        private static final String TAG = "ApiAuthenticator";
        private AccountManager accountManager;


    ApiAuthenticator(AccountManager accountManager) {
        this.accountManager = accountManager;
    }

    private static int responseCount(Response response) {
        int result = 1;
        while ((response = response.priorResponse()) != null) {
            result++;
        }
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Returns a request that includes a credential to satisfy an authentication challenge in {@code
     * response}. Returns null if the challenge cannot be satisfied.
     *
     * @param route
     * @param response
     */
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Request authenticate(@NonNull Route route, @NonNull Response response) throws IOException {
        if (response.request().url().encodedPath().startsWith("login_check") || response.request().url().encodedPath().startsWith("token"))
            return null;

        if (responseCount(response) >= 2) {
            // If both the original call and the call with refreshed token failed,
            // it will probably keep failing, so don't try again.
            return null;
        }

        for (Challenge challenge : response.challenges()) {
            if (challenge.scheme().equals("Bearer")) {
                Account[] accounts = accountManager.getAccountsByType(AuthConstants.ACCOUNT_TYPE);
                if (accounts.length != 0) {
                    String oldToken = accountManager.peekAuthToken(accounts[0], AuthConstants.AUTHTOKEN_TYPE_FULL_ACCESS);

                    if (oldToken != null) {
                        accountManager.invalidateAuthToken(AuthConstants.ACCOUNT_TYPE, oldToken);
                    }
                    try {
                        String token = accountManager.blockingGetAuthToken(accounts[0], AuthConstants.AUTHTOKEN_TYPE_FULL_ACCESS, false);

                        if (token == null) {
                            accountManager.removeAccount(accounts[0], null, null);
                        }

                        if (token != null) {
                            Request.Builder builder = response.request().newBuilder();
                            return builder.header("Authorization", "Bearer " + token).build();
                        }
                    } catch (OperationCanceledException | AuthenticatorException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Log.d(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

My repository for some function looks like this:

```
public class ApiCheckinRepository implements CheckinRepository {

    private AccountManager accountManager;

    public ApiCheckinRepository(AccountManager accountManager) {
        this.accountManager = accountManager;
    }

    @Override
    public Observable<Response<Message>> checkin(QrCode qrCode) {
       return ApiService.getInstance(accountManager).checkin(qrCode);
    }
}
```

But now I'm getting memory leaks caused by the accountManager dependency and I don't see the solution anymore...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope it will help you for resolve your problem :-

```
public class AccountLeakHandler {

    public static AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> safeGetAuthToken(AccountManager accountManager,
                                                                Account account,
                                                                String authTokenType,
                                                                Bundle options,
                                                                Activity activity,
                                                                AccountManagerCallback<Bundle> callback,
                                                                Handler handler) {
        return accountManager.getAuthToken(
                account,
                authTokenType,
                options,
                null,
                new ResolveLeakAccountManagerCallback(callback, activity),
                handler);
    }


    public static class ResolveLeakAccountManagerCallback implements AccountManagerCallback<Bundle> {

        private AccountManagerCallback<Bundle> originalCallback = null;
        private Activity originalActivity = null;

        public ResolveLeakAccountManagerCallback(AccountManagerCallback<Bundle> callback, Activity activity) {
            originalCallback = callback;
            originalActivity = activity;
        }

        @Override
        public void run(AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> future) {
            Bundle bundle = null;
            try {
                bundle = future.getResult();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // error happen
            }

            if (bundle == null) {
                callAndClear(future);
            } else {
                Intent intent = bundle.getParcelable(AccountManager.KEY_INTENT);
                if (intent != null) {
                    if (originalActivity != null) {
                        try {
                            //make FutureTask callback again
                            new RInstance(FutureTask.class, future).setValue("state", 0);
                        } catch (Exception e) {}
                        originalActivity.startActivity(intent);
                    } else {
                        callAndClear(future);
                    }
                } else {
                    callAndClear(future);
                }
            }
        }

        private void callAndClear(AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> future) {
            if (originalCallback != null) {
                originalCallback.run(future);
                originalCallback = null;
            }
            originalActivity = null;
        }
    }
}
```

for more info visit below link:-

https://github.com/square/leakcanary/issues/97

[Binder preventing garbage collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7976322/binder-preventing-garbage-collection/10668246#10668246)